# How to upgrade systemd to a specific version in ubuntu v18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, systemd, systemctl

I am using Ubuntu version 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver). The default version of systemd with this version of ubuntu is 237.

I am need to upgrade systemd to version 239.

What is the recommended procedure to do this upgrade safely?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, is systemd-v239 supported by default in any official release of ubuntu if not v18.04? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: same question here, due to bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository/+bug/1817627